# RecentFileHistory.properties in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I run NetBeans in Ubuntu. Very often I have popup shown below. How to escape from this popup. Why it is read only? Should I run NetBeans from sudo?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just don't have permissions to write in this file.

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/.netbeans
chmod +rw path-to-file-from-popup
```

and replace `user` with your username and `path-to-file-from-popup` with full file name.

You should not run netbeans under `sudo`.